# Is KL Divergence loss appropriate for generative model?

Tags: autoencoders, kullback-leibler, variational-bayes

I have coordinates data like: `x_train = [7.6291    112.74  43.232  96.636  61.033  87.311  91.55   115.28  121.22  136.48  119.52  80.53   172.08  77.987  199.21  94.94   228.03  110.2   117.83  104.26  174.62  103.42  211.92  109.35  204.29  122.91  114.44  125.46  168.69  124.61  194.97  134.78  173.77  141.56  104.26  144.11  125.46  166.99  143.26  185.64  165.3   205.14]`

Dimension is (1,42), total train samples are over (300000,42).
I want to use Variational Autoencoder to train this dataset. 
In here, I am not sure KL divergence loss is appropriate for like this data. Because, when I train without KL loss (only mse loss), model is fine. But when I train with (KL + mse loss), loss did not decrease and not changing. That is why I want to know KL loss has a limitation on data or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KL loss in VAE is similar to regularization strength - in Bayesian terms it could be weighted with how strong is your belief that the prior distribution is actually what you chose (normal distribution in VAE).

With that in mind, if your model fares worse using KL loss, you might just decrease its contribution to total loss:

Instead of 
$$\mathcal{L} = MSE + KL$$
use 
 $$\mathcal{L'} = MSE + \beta KL$$

For some $\beta$ < 1. Some people called this approach $\beta$-VAE, for example you can check out [this blogpost](https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/2018/08/12/from-autoencoder-to-beta-vae.html#beta-vae).

Comment: So, if I decrease KL contribution, should I give beta value < 1. Is there a proper way to choose beta value? By the way, when I give beta = 0.3, and train again. My reconstruction is still bad.

Comment: It's actually the other way round - if you decrease $\beta$ you decrease KL-divergence contribution. You should most likely choose $\beta$ using crossvalidation, as you would do with any other hyperparameter

Comment: I am new to machine learning. So, could you provide me some links for crossvalidation for proper seed?

Comment: Why do you use VAE then? Variational Bayes methods are very advanced, it's better to stick to simple stuff if you don't know much ML. For basics I'd recommend Andrew Ng's Coursera course.

Comment: I know about VAE and crossvalidation theory. I mean some sample code link for crossvalidation for NN. By the way, how do you think VAE is convenient on noisy data?

Comment: I do not think you should start with VAE at all - you should look into simpler algorithms like PCA first. For code I suggest reading through appropriate scikit-learn documentation (it has functions/classes for crossvalidation)